# How to understand tedious tension questions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> A rope is wrapped $M$ whole turns round a cylindrical post, the two ends of the rope going in opposite directions. The coefficient of the friction between rope and post is 0.25. It is desired that by pulling with a force of 1$N$ on one end of the rope, I can prevent the rope from moving away from me even if a force of $10^6N$ is applied to the other end. How large does $M$ have to be?

Does 'prevent the rope from moving' imply limiting friction larger than the force applied? How shall I attempt this question?

What is the nature behind my ability in pulling against a force which is much larger than mine? Is it because of the additional friction exerted in the rope? Will the rope break down due to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a FBD for a small angular section of the rope (subtending an angle $\delta\theta$), showing the normal reaction from the pulley and the friction force when the system is about to slip and then let $\delta\theta\to0$. You should get:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\,T}{\mathrm{d}\,\theta} = -\mu\,T$$

subject to $T(0) = 10^6{\rm N}$ where $\theta$ is the angular position on the pulley, and the angle increases *away* from the load that you are supporting. If you  solve this initial value problem you can find what tension you need at $\theta=\pi$ and also you can see where the peak tension is and therefore where the rope is likeliest to break.